# ttk.OptionMenu doesn't recognize variable

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a project using tkinter where I have 3 different ttk.OptionMenu widgets. Below is the relevant code:

```
mes_escolhido = StringVar()
ano_escolhido = IntVar()
drop_mes = ttk.OptionMenu(frame_selecao, mes_escolhido, Settings.LISTA_MESES[Settings.mes_atual-1], *Settings.LISTA_MESES)
drop_ano = ttk.OptionMenu(frame_selecao, ano_escolhido, Settings.LISTA_ANOS[Settings.LISTA_ANOS.index(Settings.ano_atual)], *Settings.LISTA_ANOS)
tipo_escolhido = StringVar()
drop_tipo = ttk.OptionMenu(frame_selecao, tipo_escolhido, Settings.LISTA_TIPOS[0], *Settings.LISTA_TIPOS)

button_editentry = ttk.Button(frame_selecao, text='Editar entrada', command=lambda: print(tipo_escolhido.get(), mes_escolhido.get(), ano_escolhido.get()))
```

Here is the Settings.py:

```
LISTA_TIPOS = [
    'Fixas',
    'Supermercado',
    'Delivery',
    'Restaurante',
    'Faxina',
    'Gasolina',
    'Transporte',
    'Empresa',
    'Grandes',
    'Outras'
]

LISTA_MESES = [
    'Janeiro',
    'Fevereiro',
    'Março',
    'Abril',
    'Maio',
    'Junho',
    'Julho',
    'Agosto',
    'Setembro',
    'Outubro',
    'Novembro',
    'Dezembro'
]

LISTA_ANOS = [
    2020,
    2021,
    2022,
    2023,
    2024,
    2025,
    2026,
    2027,
    2028,
    2029,
    2030
]
```

Of course I have imported Settings.

For some reason the script prints correctly the value of mes_escolhido and ano_escolhido, but prints an empty string for tipo_escolhido.

I can't figure out why. Can anyone understand it?

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve].

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine.